# MongoDB create DB from files

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to install an app with nodeJS(totalJS) and MongoDB. When I run my nodeJS server it says that I have no db and I have to create it from a folder. How can I create a mongoDB from a folder of JSON files ?

I am not good at nodeJS so maybe it's my mongodb ling that is wrong ?
database                 : mongodb://127.0.0.1/data/db
Then I start my mongo server I use --dbpath /data/db parameters and I have copied JSON files into this folder but it's not reconized them.

Can you help me ?

Comment: If you are starting with JSON files you need to import those into MongoDB using a tool like [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/]). MongoDB stores data on disk in a binary format, so JSON files will not be recognized if you copy them into the `dbpath`. Are you certain you have JSON files? If they are definitely JSON you should be able to preview in a text editor. If your files are a backup from another MongoDB deployment it would be helpful to include a file listing as that may be more identifiable.

Comment: yes I have JSON file and I have imported them fine. The problem is in fact when I run the nodeJS server I will ask to the developper of this project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`/data/db` is mongodb's default folder for storage, so in order to start your mongodb service you need to create one or specify an other one  with `--dbpath my/other/folder`;

`mongodb://127.0.0.1/data/db` is not a good uri for connection, usually you will have something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1/database` where `database` is the name of your database.

But if you use some specific framework, do not know like `sails.js` then you need to specify it in the question, we can't help you otherwise.